# is MapReduce usefull for processing big files, crawling a lot of pages for data and inserting them in Hbase?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-streaming

I have some python scripts that I run every day, these scripts do this stuff :

```
parse 1000 text files (gziped) :
    ~ 100 GB 
    30 Millions rows
Crawl some data from many websites : 
    40 Millions rows    
    Script distributed in 50 Amazon EC2 micro instances (5 scripts / instance)
```

For every row I do some stuff like (be sure if the row don't exist, search some data in database that I need to add with my row before inserting) and finally, I insert the row in Hbase and Solr.
To process all these files and crawl all these pages, it takes a lot of time, even if I distribute my scripts in several machines .

I don't use MapReduce for now, my question is : Is MapReduce will be usefull in my case? (I learned a little about it and what I understand is that I will realy need it if I want to do some calculs in a number of files like wordCount example)

Comment: MapReduce is efficient for big data processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapReduce is programming paradigm implemented by different distributors (Apache, Google, ...). If you want to process your data using MapReduce you need to configure cluster and store your data in Distributive File System (hdfs or other implementations known by Hadoop).
And yes, mapreduce job will parallel processing between different nodes in cluster and save your time.